# Bash script escaping single quotes unnecessarily

Tags: bash

**test.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

userId=$1

set -x

function runQuery {
    output=$(sf data query --query = "\"SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '$userId'\"")
    echo $output
}

runQuery
```

I have the above bash script which takes user id as argument and uses it run a command

Expected : `sf data query --query="SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005'"`

Actual: `sf data query --query = '"SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '\''005'\''"'`

What am I doing wrong? I am running the script as `sh test.sh 005`

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

Comment: @GillesQuénot This will probably not fix OP's problem here. The problem seems to be `sf ... --query = "\"...\""` and not the unquoted `echo $output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No space allowed around `=`, so

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

userId=$1

set -x

function runQuery {
    printf -v output "sf data query --query=\042SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '$userId';\042"
    echo "$output" | bash
}
```

And I edited code to simplify quotes.

Comment: I just tried this and debug output shows that command that is executed as `sf data query '--query='\''SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = 005;'\'''` but what I am looking for is `sf data query --query="SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005'"`

Comment: Did you tried last edit?

Comment: Yes, I just tried again.

Comment: Try one more time, post edited accordingly

Comment: It now prints correctly but when I take that output and try to run as `$($output)`, it is doing the same.

Comment: Edited post accordingly

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Why did you construct a bash command (stored under the misleading name *output*) just to immediately run it? Wouldn't it be way easier, shorter, and safer to run the command directly?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your confusion comes from bash's quoting rules. From the perspective of bash, below arguments are all equal.

- `a=b`
- `a="b"`
- `"a=b"`
- `'a=b'`
- `"a"'='"b"`

After bash processed this quoting step, it passes the resulting string argument (literally `a=b` in above example) on to the program (in your case `sf`). Bash does not interpret the `-` or `=` here -- `sf` does!

It seems you assumed `sf data query` expects three arguments `--query`, `=` and `"SELECT ..."`, the last one with literal quotes!
This would be *very* unusual and I couldn't find any hints in [`sf`'s documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm) regarding such an oddity.

From the documentation (and convention) I would assume you need one of the following:

```
sf data query --query="SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '$userId'"
```

or

```
sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '$userId'"
```

With those, `sf` will get the literal argument `SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005'` (assuming `$userId` was `005`).

Also, you don't have to capture the output (`output=$(...)`) just to echo it again:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -x
userId=$1
runQuery() {
  sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '$userId'"
}
runQuery
```